# Locust Load Testing in Python: Requires Login to Website, any advise?

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, load-testing, locust

There is a localhost website requiring Load Testing (lets call it `https://localhost/hompeage`). However, to get to the Website needing Load Testing I have to login through a Company Login Page (lets call it `https://vpn.company.com/login`). This Login is required every time and doesn't save.

## Selenium in Python Works

Now I know the proper sequence to login vi Selenium, including the Web Element IDs. See the Python file below (which works as an `__init__` for my Functional Test Cases):

**website.py**

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Website:
    def __init__(self, browser: str, username: str, password: str):
        try:
            if browser == "Chrome":
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            elif browser == "Edge":
                self.driver = webdriver.Edge()
        except:
            print("Only 'Chrome' and 'Edge' browsers are supported for testing.")
            sys.exit(1)
        
        self.driver.get("https://localhost/homepage")
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source # Scan the page
        not_private1 = "Your connection is not private"
        not_private2 = "Your connection isn't private"
        if (not_private1 in get_source or not_private2 in get_source):
            # NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click() # Click "Advanced" button
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # Scroll to the bottom of the page
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click() # Click "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" link
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source # Redirects to Corporate Login Page
        login_page = "Login Page"
        if (login_page in get_source):
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys(password)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
            time.sleep(1)

      # connects to the homepage
    
    def close(self):
        self.driver.close() # Closes the browser
```

(The above could probably be more efficient by just connecting straight to `https://vpn.company.com/login` instead of going through the `"Your connection isn't private"` piece, which is just going to take me to the `https://vpn.company.com/login` page anyways)

## Locust: "Login" Method

As for Locust, I've been made aware I cannot use Selenium and I have to rely upon Locust-specific Python Code (I tried putting the `__init__` code into `def on_start` already). Here is my Locust file thus far:

**locust.py**

```
import time
import webbrowser

from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    # HttpUser is the User Agent who can visit different endpoints
    wait_time = between(1, 5) # How long it takes visiting an endpoint before it starts visiting another one
    
    def on_start(self):
        login_page = "https://vpn.company.com/login"
        self.client.get(login_page)

        post_data = {"usernameInput":"TestUser", "passwordInput":"Test123", "Submit":"submitButton"}
        self.client.post(login_page, post_data)
        time.sleep(1)
    
    @task
    def landing_page(self):
        self.client.get(url="/")
    
    #@task
    #def about_page(self):
    #    self.client.get(url="/#about")
    
    # Connect to Locust Page (in new tab, if possible)
    webbrowser.open("http://localhost:8089", new = 2)
```

(Is `"Submit":"submitButton"` correct? At least I remember seeing an ecample of `self.client.post` that included `Submit` before the CSS Element ID)

### Locust Testing: "Login" Method

To run this test, I run the following command in Terminal: `locust -f locust.py --host https://localhost/homepage --users 5 --spawn-rate 20`

#### Results

Here is the output when I run the `locust` command:

```
C:\Users\Adam\eclipse-workspace\TestProject4>locust -f libraries\\locust.py --host https://localhost/homepage --users 5 --spawn-rate 20
[2023-05-24 10:39:16,812] vm-w10/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all netwo
rk interfaces)
[2023-05-24 10:39:16,830] vm-w10/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.15.1
[2023-05-24 10:39:20,907] vm-w10/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 5 users at a rate of 20.00 per second
[2023-05-24 10:39:20,910] vm-w10/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"WebsiteUser": 5} (5 total users)
```

In the Locust Web Application, I get back the following results:

| Type | Name | #Requests | #Fails |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GET | /homepage/ | 13 | 13 |
| GET | /login | 5 | 0 |
| POST | /login | 10 | 0 |

From this, I can assume that the initial `GET` is connecting to `https://vpn.company.com/login`, and the `POST` is *maybe* correct? Obviously the `GET` to the Homepage isn't connecting. I've thought "perhaps in the delay between authentication and connecting to the website?" so I added `time.sleep(1)` but that hasn't changed the results of what Locust returns (not even sure if Locust recognizes `time.sleep`).

If I `CTRL + C` in the Terminal, I get back the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\_ffi\loop.py", line 270, in python_check_callback
    def python_check_callback(self, watcher_ptr): # pylint:disable=unused-argument

KeyboardInterrupt
2023-05-24T14:42:14Z
[2023-05-24 10:42:14,476] vm-w10/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 1)
Type     Name                                                         # reqs      # fails |    Avg     Min     Max    Med |   req/s  failures/s
--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|-------|-------------|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------|-----------
GET      /homepage/                                                        13  13(100.00%) |     22      18      37     21 |    1.76        1.76
GET      /login
       5     0(0.00%) |    300 
    204     506    260 |    0.68        0.00
POST     /login
       5     0(0.00%) |     71 
     59      77     75 |    0.68        0.00
--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|-------|-------------|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------|-----------
         Aggregated                                                       23   13(56.52%) |     93      18     506     37 |    3.11        1.76

Response time percentiles (approximated)
Type     Name                                                                 50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%  99.9% 99.99
Error report
# occurrences      Error
------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13                 GET /homepage/: SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certific
ate (_ssl.c:1002)')
------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Locust: "Cookie" Method

An Admin recommended I try using a Cookie (he also told me that the login method is *probably* via SAML Token, but he wasn't fully sure). So instead of Login, I found what I believe is the Cookie after I login to the page. I updated my Code so it's using the Cookie as a Token (not sure I'm doing this right):

**locust.py**

```
import time
import webbrowser

from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    # HttpUser is the User Agent who can visit different endpoints
    wait_time = between(1, 5) # How long it takes visiting an endpoint before it starts visiting another one
    
    def on_start(self):
        login_page = "https://vpn.company.com/login"
        self.client.get(login_page)

        cookie = ".AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8MTHe7hMbp5IvzCac79rZkiG3Tb_tarAITryM-FPR2oZzF5wGHBAVTqIKaIGSOGQZ_CkAeD0M0wOXmRuL0cgRpY6da6K5Ftpod0Ygj3BVxI2ybu5VNUY_RhLGpLuiWI-4BwJKBGtpE1MKhIoB0uq0amGMHFM4jeSYh_TeR21aHWkVXLjmLvT_q_PqNbqIXubK7hHaAk5lwa0pEJ8mZYZE5ZHM-vYL7iid-vWI8IWVLieLIALGOsKEp7W0GHX1cHT2-y_F4O7xBuRidl41xMjGc3V6RLRzrQ1LGFSRwrvNIWksa5IyW-8GtMIIYmNClIPtVgJEgunwWrnwdu3odr28F3bQabc2VPGtk3mW-3QgarNUJxAkGuAM943bUdFKPHyCj6L-2LJGL9EANBWg0Do6wSGy-iXoFb_1aHhzybgzZqy7Cj6xmG_jCDZNWm1sUXySW6meE9BMa2IcG_DZc-kdMsBYOXDn8rw0SHoRlIOwVlVIgOxv13lqMJbHjCp4cEuNwcuqMCWNkX6QB5eFTeqr78fo2g1b90jQfQIi5fD0rs0rMw3m38FMtOBo1Mx0fYNpyQu0iP7FjoWzW37LtxXZCrZtd1lQwv8SbJtcdsz2Q9RQtMq7v-9PXj33uuvRgZtMFApCi0pUSsjM6eeP2cOHKx-woMrGdfGcsdyMzjgHB5ioMpZyqyTmsxjyZmTrGN2Mc_eixGRZnQi0SmQwcZSuCJzirseFzE440UcjXEZbW6Xgt-oMPQes_6VWRLR6fYqB4Cp7Nuzoxgd2RcRHfd7p6uvGTp5nX66oXom-8dsZRRXiagFNUcQPTXplJ8JVPPIip1-T_9jd_JWVLVMxv2ROfh4ftZu0hgzRdrtKJITCnBqzLHzw9BZa0WJabayvdWZMlbhQsJ2RwI4vDIf-uMBMLaSs--iKurKr3AVpgsGRVwYtEs2ZnhGIQDSFSbb4ZPXtz4KZb5pRneZwenGdbuDMMy83sMZHdZ7BHq1vRg7cq2khRVCatUZ467kBaCgKVucjE8TlxKs9t4XvsrQXYgf63zZZf1SNPt1bP-c1E9gNWODoWSLn999Apx_TfusjNY4zCoPMo8ZvrZzZx4UEKeEjiZY-F9k0z873f373wWhdd9QaEpGQiZzhk6fyrvaMjifhN4JLLOKPVOzOsNadRSkJnPRzBzZokmOzybVNc0gkcVp9pfUbcvSHePgazxpSn6Iw4JhN-m0Dj8PAfLGQwqoDLgNCzyNp35x8kBzP-ONbdL1EJbicf9en5ypRmD4oH7QXxVXuigecJnDlvZz4n-aB4D"
        self.client.post(login_page, {"token": cookie})
        time.sleep(1)
    
    @task
    def landing_page(self):
        self.client.get(url="/")
    
    #@task
    #def about_page(self):
    #    self.client.get(url="/#about")
    
    # Connect to Locust Page (in new tab, if possible)
    webbrowser.open("http://localhost:8089", new = 2)
```

### Locust Testing: "Cookie" Method

Exactly the same as the "Login" Method Results. So either I'm doing both authentication methods correctly and it's just not recognizing the Homepage (of which I'm doubtful) OR both the "Login" and "Cookie" Method I'm doing incorrectly.

## Ultimate Question

**What am I doing wrong?** I'd prefer to use the "Login" method (and I assume the issue is related to the "Sign In" button), but any method to login and have `GET` for `https://localhost/hompeage` to return no Failures in Locust, so I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Thanks go out to a Python Expert I spoke with.

I was right to pursue the SAML Token Route ("Cookies" Method), but I needed more then just the Cookies. I needed to copy the **cURL (bash)** code (Right click -> `Inspect` page -> In **DevTools**, `Network` -> Right-click the `GET 200` Header 9for the successful login) -> `Copy` -> `Copy as cURL (bash)`), convert that code to Python (which should include `cookies` and `headers`) and then include the Cookies and Headers as the `self.client.post` method for login. Not the easiest process, but it thankfully got done!

[Here is my updated code.](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/adohusavem) I plan to make the `cookies` and `headers` proper Globals that I can reference in all future `@task`s. `on_start` is no longer required.